# Lazyload and Masonry on mobile

Tags: masonry, lazy-loading

I have a code working pretty well on desktop, but my images on mobiles take too long to load and sometimes isn't loading at all... any help?

code

.js

`(function(a) {
    var b = a(".grid").masonry({
        itemSelector: ".grid-item",
        columnWidth: 306,
        fitWidth: !0,
        transitionDuration: 0
    });
    b.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
        b.masonry("layout");
        a(".loading").hide();
        a(".grid").show();
    });
    a(document).ready(function() {
        a("img.imgload").lazyload({
            threshold: 430,
            failure_limit: 10
        });
    });
})(jQuery);`

.html

```
<div class="loading"></div>
<div class="grid">
<div class="grid-item"><a href="blablabla" class="main"><img class="imgload" src="/img/dummy.jpg" data-original="blablabla" width="300" height="420"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

.css
`.loading {position: fixed;left: 0;top: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: 9999;background: url(/img/modal-loader.gif) center no-repeat #fff }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue:

```
    a(document).ready(function() {
```